# Difference between VMware LAN Segment and Virtual Network

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, virtual-network

What exactly is the difference between LAN Segments and Virtual Networks in VMware?

**LAN Segments** don't have any configuration options, at least in the GUI:

[LAN Segment configuration GUI in VMware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR2IF.png)

**Virtual Networks** can be configured in the Virtual Network Editor, and include the default Auto-bridging, Host-only and NAT configurations:

[Virtual Network Editor GUI in VMware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJMdA.png)

But what are the differences exactly?

Virtual Networks can be configured to connect to the host or not, to connect to the outside internet or not.
Do LAN Segments connect to the host or the outside internet (by default)?
Are there customization options for LAN Segments?

*Note: Please avoid citing from the official VMware documentation, because I find it hard to understand and it does not provide an overview about the differences.*

Comment: I only use WMware Workstation, and I can't find mentions of VLAN in the GUI.
In uni I have learnt about VLANs in real networks, but currently I'm referring to what I see in the menu. Please see the two links to the screenshots (unfortunately I couldn't embed the images, as I am a new user on this forum).

The screenshots were taken in Workstation 15.5.6, but I checked, and the naming is the same in the current Workstation.

Comment: Thank you for linking the answer, however I have already checked it and others found with searching for containing both "lan segment" and "virtual network".
Neither the answers nor the official documentation is explicit about which network type does what.

Comment: Lan segments are a private network that can be shared with other virtual machines on the host, that's it. They need a DHCP server or you manually assign IPs to the VMs, there is nothing to configure on the segment itself.  A virtual network is just that, a configurable network, not a segment.